# Determine the solubility of peg-solitaire (solo-noble)

Tags: peg-solitaire

Are there specific patterns we can look in a single configuration of a square peg solitaire game which we can use to determine whether we can win the game from there or not?

Comment: Have you even Googled "mathematics of peg solitaire"? Try this Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire#Studies_on_peg_solitaire

Comment: Also this gem: http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/15859-s11/notes/peg-solitaire.pdf

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. A quick Google search brings up a few pages which look at characteristics of peg solitaire positions, I didn't find anything about how to determine whether a position has a solution or not. Obviously it's possible to exhaustively search all possible moves, but I'd be interested to know if there is a neater way to determine if a solution exists.

Comment: @Pieter Thanks, I think that wikipedia link answers my question.